# Maven Deployment on Tomcat: only .java files in webapps

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Using Maven and Tomcat 7.0.42

When my war files get deployed on my tomcat, I get a ClassNotFoundException. When looking into the folder on my tomcat, I only see a .java there but no .class file. Now just starting the server once again (as I did a lot recently) and it has the .class file. Didn't change anything! I just heard that we use the wtp plugin to deploy. Does this help?

What happened here?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>SVIS3GWebDruck</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>de.svi.svis3g</groupId>
        <artifactId>SVIS3G_Fragments</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local_tomcat_admin_app_deploy</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.1-sr-1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Container configuration -->
                            <container>
                                <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                                <type>remote</type>
                            </container>
                            <configuration>
                                <type>runtime</type>
                                <properties>
                                    <cargo.remote.username>admin</cargo.remote.username>
                                    <cargo.remote.password>pwd</cargo.remote.password>
                                    <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>http://localhost:8080/manager</cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
                                </properties>
                            </configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>local_tomcat_deploy</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.1-sr-1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Container configuration -->
                            <container>
                                <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                            </container>
                            <configuration>
                                <type>existing</type>
                                <home>B:\applicationserver\apache-tomcat-7.0.42</home>
                            </configuration>
                            <deployer>
                                <deployables>
                                    <deployable>
                                        <artifactId>SVIS3GWebDruck</artifactId>
                                        <groupId>de.svi.svis3g</groupId>
                                        <type>war</type>
                                    </deployable>
                                </deployables>
                            </deployer>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>vt_tomcat_deploy</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-container</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-container</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <container>
                                <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                                <type>remote</type>
                            </container>
                            <configuration>
                                <type>runtime</type>
                                <properties>
                                    <cargo.remote.username>admin</cargo.remote.username>
                                    <cargo.remote.password>pwd</cargo.remote.password>
                                    <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>${ServerURL}/manager</cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
                                </properties>
                            </configuration>
                            <deployer>
                                <deployables>
                                    <deployable>
                                        <artifactId>SVIS3GWebDruck</artifactId>
                                        <groupId>de.svi.svis3g</groupId>
                                        <type>war</type>
                                    </deployable>
                                </deployables>
                            </deployer>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.caucho.hessian</groupId>
            <artifactId>hessian</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.svi.svis3g</groupId>
            <artifactId>SVIS3GBirt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.svi.svis3g</groupId>
            <artifactId>SVIS3GCommons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.svi.svis3g</groupId>
            <artifactId>SVIS3GBusiness</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.svi.svis3g</groupId>
            <artifactId>SVIS3GBirtAPI</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
      <groupId>de.svi.svis3g</groupId>
      <artifactId>SVIS3GEISIntegrationAPI</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.svi.svis3g</groupId>
      <artifactId>SVIS3GEISIntegrationEVBDruck</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.svi.svis3g</groupId>
            <artifactId>SVIS3GEVBDruckWSGen</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SVIS3GWebDruck</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/de/svi/svis3g/birt/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>de/svi/svis3g/birt/resources</targetPath>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <webResources>
              <resource>
                <directory>target</directory>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </resource>
            </webResources>
          </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Not 100% sure whether this even is the relevant part. The thing is that it was already running properly and I never changed anything on the pom.xml. Only thing could be dependency updates by the repository.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your pom.xml and your directory structure? Most likely the problem lies there.

Comment: Probably you didn't add maven compile plugin to build part of pom.xml

Comment: Which directory structure are you talking about?

Comment: Post the project structure and complete pom.xml.

Comment: still not getting what "project structure" you mean, except if you mean that I have 3 projects named SVIS3GWebDruck, SVIS3GWebOIV and SVIS3GWebAccessOIV, where WebOIV is the parent and WebDruck is another parent